# Generating PDF with get/set variables

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, show

The variables value1 to value4 are needed to display in the PDF through the iText PDF generator. When I use the value, it shows "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field value1". How could I fix that?
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class GenerateSummonPDF
{
private String value1;
private String value2;
private String value3;
private String value4;   //this variables with constant updated string data

public  String getValue1()
{
    return this.value1;

}


public void userdata(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4)
{

    this.value1 = p1;
    this.value2 = p2;
    this.value3 = p3;
    this.value4 = p4;



}
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  Document document = new Document();
  try
  {
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\enforement system\\Summon PDF list\\Serial No.pdf"));
     document.open();
     document.add(new Paragraph(getValue1()); //i need to print all the data here from the userdata
     document.close();
     writer.close();
  } catch (DocumentException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of `GenerateSummonPDF`to call non-static methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GenerateSummonPDF generateSummonPDF = new GenerateSummonPDF(); //create an instance
    generateSummonPDF.userdata("TestString1", "TestString2", "TestString3", "TestString4"); //some content

    Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\enforement system\\Summon PDF list\\Serial No.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph(generateSummonPDF.getValue1()); //get value1
        document.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (DocumentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had tried but in the PDF generated shows "TestString1" instead of the data parsing to the "userdata(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4)".

Comment: When we call `generateSummonPDF.userdata("TestString1", "TestString2", "TestString3", "TestString4");`, "TestString1" is stored in the field `value1`.
Replace the arguments of this method with your own data or delete this line and call the `userdata()`-Method somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the values from the static methods, so that you are getting this error, Just create a function and place your code there like this..

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      createPdf();
  }
createPdf(){
  Document document = new Document();
  try
  {
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\enforement system\\Summon PDF list\\Serial No.pdf"));
     document.open();
     document.add(new Paragraph(getValue1()); //i need to print all the data here from the userdata
     document.close();
     writer.close();
  } catch (DocumentException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Now you are calling a non-static method from a static one. Consider creating an instance first...

Comment: not quite understand could you explain in more detail, what do you mean by "create PDF"?

Comment: When you are calling the non static methods in static method, then you should create/call the object's method like `new GenerateSummonPDF().getValue1()` or put the non-static methods aside in a separate method.